# How to track applications configuration files modifications

Tags: version-control, github, application-settings

I often change the user settings of one of my applications (Submlime Text 2) adding a little modifications now and then + testing a lot of new plugins.

I wanted to be able to track the modifications I make and was thinking about using Github but I was told it is not recommended for security reasons.

So I tried to find how to install Git locally (Mac OS X 10.8.5) but didn't find any helpful ressource.

What I would like to achieve is :

- be able to revert to an older configuration (if I, for example discover conflicts in my new configuration, or duplicates features)
- having a log of the modifications I do to my user settings (ie "On X/X/13 added Package Control").

Any ressource on how to install git locally would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed **`git-core`** on Mac (as mentioned in "[Getting Started - Installing Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)", with MacPorts, `sudo port install git-core +doc`), you will see that git doesn't keep a log of who does what.

You would need to add an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html)** for that.
It does have its own audit log.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Your answer looked like a chicken and egg problem (1) + terse (2). I knew nothing about ST2 + github => Where to start? Plus, I've to say I'm not a fan of macports... So I took some time and started learning ST2 + did some research. I think  Looks like you've perfectly answered my question :-)